# Im Äußeren in the sense of "in appearance"

Tags: word-usage

Can "Im Äußeren" be used in the sense of "in appearance".

Can I say:

> Die beiden Modelle ähneln sich im Äußeren.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not incorrect, but I wouldn't normally say it that way, I would instead use the adjective "äußerlich" that says it clearer. The noun "das Äußere" is a more ambiguous word that isn't clearly associated with appearance.

> Die beiden Modelle ähneln sich äußerlich.

Other idiomatic alternatives:

> Die beiden Modelle ähneln sich im Aussehen.
> Die beiden Modelle ähneln sich optisch.  *(they look similar)*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but I would prefer this version:

> Die beiden Modelle ähneln sich in der äußeren Erscheinung.

- das Äußere = the outside
- die Erscheinung = the appearance, the look
- die äußere Erscheinung = how they appear/look from outside